# Sphinx search - exclude from results by condition

Tags: php, sphinx

Is there a way to execute search by some condition?

I saw there is `SetFilter` option, but it seems it's not what I need.

I would like to exclude all results, which have empty some column (e.g. company_title). But I don't see that I can define it like that using `SetFilter` (or I'm missing something)?

this is how it looks like atm:

```
$results = SphinxSearch::search($search, 'profiles')
                        ->setSelect('id')
                        ->setMatchMode(\Sphinx\SphinxClient::SPH_MATCH_ALL)
                        ->limit(65, $skip);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you can't directly, because the sphinx index doesnt know which columns are empty (it indexes the text content, not the lack of content :)

So you would have to create an attribute to store that fact

```
sql_query = SELECT id, company_title, IF(company_title='',1,0) AS empty_title, ... 

sql_attr_bool = empty_title
```

Then you CAN use it with setFilter

```
->setFilter('empty_title',array(0));
```